# Reaper DAW and OMF files

Tags: omf, reaper

Hi guys,

I want to do some final sound mixing in Reaper but it cannot open the OMF files!  Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: @Andre does Reaper support a video track for sync?

Comment: @VCProd  Yes it does and thats what puzzles me!  Is OMF a standard out there in the final mix world?   Or is it a nasty flavor left behind by Avid?

Comment: @Andre OMF is still a standard, but it seems like other options are being used now - PT sessions, etc.  I have never encountered OMFs in the indie film world, but that doesn't mean too much :)

Comment: OK, I found out that most TV production company's here in South Africa export their edits to OMF and we have to make do with them...I guess I shall have to extract via Sound Track Pro and then edit and output in Reaper...going to have some hiccups I'm certain!

Comment: @Andre - aatranslator seems to have a good relationship with Reaper, by the way the forums look.  I'd be curious how the OMF import goes.. keep us posted!

Comment: BTW .mov (Quicktime file) is not a codec while .avi is. So just having a .mov extension doesn't actually tell you anything about the video file. In fact if you have a .avi codec installed in Quicktime that .avi file will show up as a Quicktime file. SO.... On the Mac you do need the codec to be supported by Quicktime but if you are having sync issues then you may well need to convert to a different codec. Very lossy codecs like MP4 or h.264 can cause glitches unless you make them with keyframes a lot more often that the default.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Reaper allows for OMF import. I remember a while back I wanted to give Reaper an honest try, but it didn't support OMF so gave up. It's been a while so they may have added this functionality. Although based on your question, I take it they didn't :-)

Comment: @Andrew Thanks Andrew, I have been pointed at a software app that will allow me to import it but that kind of defeats the object...

Comment: @Andre what is the app?

Comment: @Andrew  Here's the link: http://www.aatranslator.com.au/

Comment: @Andrew - You really should give reaper a try regardless of the OMF support. I really love it as a sound design environment. It's very different from Pro Tools, but it's not all that hard to pick up. It's as deep as you want it to be since it's a more flexible environment. There's stuff in there that no other DAW's do (and I've tried them all since the days of Opcode Studio Vision). I primarily use PT for post (and still will), but I've been using Reaper more and more and I really love it (it has rewire support as well, so sync'ing the two shouldn't be an issue).

Comment: I played a little with it and found it really interesting. I will delve into it at some point. I appreciate your nudge! 

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after some pondering, I went ahead and got AA Translator - cheap $160 license for the full version.

I have an OMF exported from FCP with an mp4 guide track.  The OMF properly translated to a Reaper rpp project file and it also exported to a Sony Vegas EDL text file.  Both files opened up perfectly without any problems.

Only issue:  Neither load to Reaper or Vegas contained the video file (an mp4).  I wonder if the OMF did not contain the video file and they just made a reference track after the fact.  Not a big deal for Vegas - the OMF log told me all the offsets were 00:00, so I just dropped it in and the video file lined up no problem with everything.

Reaper, on the other hand, only loaded the audio from the mp4 file, no video.  Are you sure Reaper can view a video track?  Reaper definitely works for the audio, but not being able to track with the video will still leave me using Vegas.

Comment: Yes, reaper can load a video track, however... you don't see it as a track. You only see the audio as a track. You need to go into the "View" menu and show your video. Also, if you mute the guide/video audio track it mutes your video, so you have to manually turn down the audio slider. It's a little quirky, but Ive been starting to do more post in Reaper and scoring to video and I'm really starting to get used to it. Last weekend I did Sound Design and Music in Reaper for this: http://bit.ly/hqJiHR I do agree the lack of OMF support is a major PITA, but it is with every DAW, so oh well.

Comment: @VCProd Thanks for the feedback regarding AA Translator.  I actually decided to bite the bullet and purchased Pro Tools 9.0 and I am impressed by it!  Got a long and steep learning curve to go through ahead of me, tho I find quiet similar to most other DAWS I Have used
and I know I will still use Reaper in the interim...I love it's simplicity of use!


Comment: @Syndicate Synthetique Thanks for the link...good luck with the project.

Comment: Incidentally, I did the project I was talking about by importing the OMF's into Sound Track Pro and then exported the files and worked them in Reaper and exported them to WAV format and sent that back to the editor and all was hunky dory.  So alls well that ends well!  :)
I did have some hairy moments with sync issues but managed to overcome!


Comment: @Syndicate - oo, excellent, thanks for that Reaper info!  I'm excited about starting to use it.  OMF doesn't bother me so much now that I have a way to handle it on my own terms.  They told me I'd have to use PT - never, I say!

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with reaper, but I know that Ptools does not play well with others because of the their insistence on separate L and R files.  Getting OMF between PT and Nuendo is a bitch unless you buy SSDs $600 conversion software (which i have never used, but has a good rep on the boards).

Answer (score 0):

Yea, reaper does not natively support OMF.  Reaper in general is weak to sync / working with video.

I just wish someone could fix the AAF from sony vegas to pro tools problem.

Comment: @Sean AA Translator can probably do the in-between for you.  

Comment: @Sean I used to have sync/playback issues with Reaper on PC until I found out that the sync issues you're experiencing are likely due to the video file format. On mac you have to use .mov, on pc you have to use .avi. Once I started using the OS native format I stopped having those issues.